# QR Scanning in Appcelerator without Ti Barcode module

Tags: android, iphone, appcelerator, qr-code

Wanted to check if there is any way to scan a QR code on Android / iPhone using Appcelerator without using the Titanium Barcode module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is a great library to get QR-scanning support in your Android app.

However, it is written in Java, so not available for iOS.

Comment: There's a port to iOS of ZXing and the QR code support in the port is solid.

Answer (score 0):

ZXing has both Java and Objective C/C++ ports, both of which have strong QR code support. In fact, the Appcelerator module is based ZXing. You'd have to figure out how to integrate the ZXing code into Appcelerator, effectively duplicating what Appcelerator has done. I've no idea how to do that.